# Convert Powershell script into VBA string

Tags: vba, powershell

I've created a script into Powershell ISE which works well :

```
$Connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$Cmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand

#Connection
$Server = "*****"
$Database = "****"
$User ="******"
$Pwd = "******"
$Connection.ConnectionString = "Server= $Server; Database= $Database; 
Integrated Security= False; uid= $User; Password= $Pwd;"
$Connection.Open()

#Execute query
[string]$Query = Get-Content "C:\Users\****\Desktop\testSQL.sql"
$cmd = $connection.CreateCommand()
$cmd.CommandText = $Query
if ($cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() -ne -1)
{
echo "Failed";
}

$Connection.Close()
```

I manage to call this script from MS Access with VBA.

```
Public Sub Script()
    Dim ScriptPath As String
    ScriptPath = "C:\Users\****\Desktop\Reprise_Besoins_2018.ps1"
    Call Shell("powershell -noexit -command powershell.exe -Executionpolicy 
    Bypass -file " & ScriptPath, vbMaximizedFocus)
End Sub
```

I'd like to call directly this code from vba without using a file script.ps1.
I tried this :

```
Public Sub Script2()
Dim ScriptText As String
ScriptText = "$Connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection " & vbCrLf & _
            "$Cmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand" & vbCrLf & _
            "$Server = '****' " & vbCrLf & _
            "$Database = '****' " & vbCrLf & _
            "$User ='****' " & vbCrLf & _
            "$Pwd = '****' " & vbCrLf & _
            "$Connection.ConnectionString = 'Server= $Server; Database= $Database; Integrated Security= False; uid= $User; Password= $Pwd;'" & vbCrLf & _
            "$Connection.Open() " & vbCrLf & _
            "[string]$Query = Get-Content 'C:\Users\****\Desktop\testSQL.sql' " & vbCrLf & _
            "$cmd = $connection.CreateCommand() " & vbCrLf & _
            "$cmd.CommandText = $Query " & vbCrLf & _
            "if ($cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() -ne -1)" & vbCrLf & _
            "{echo 'Failed' } " & vbCrLf & _
            "$Connection.Close() "

Call Shell("PowerShell -noexit powershell.exe  -Executionpolicy Bypass -Command" & ScriptText, vbNormalFocus)
End Sub
```

I tried with différent kind of quote without success.
Any ideas ?

Comment: Just curious what this has to do with Bash? Also, the script block needs to have curly braces around it.

Comment: Why call PowerShell twice in your command line?

Comment: Also there is no space between `-Command` and the text of the script that you want to execute.

Answer (score 0):

You could encode your script to base64 and utilize `powershell.exe -EncodedCommand`

---

From the `powershell.exe` help document:

```
# To use the -EncodedCommand parameter:
$command = 'dir "c:\program files" '
$bytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($command)
$encodedCommand = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($bytes)
powershell.exe -encodedCommand $encodedCommand
```

In your case, assign your script text to `$command` using a here-string:

```
$command = @'
    script text here
'@
```

Be sure to use a single-quoted here-string so the variables aren't interpreted.

At this point, you can copy the output of `$encodedCommand` and put it into your vbscript.